# How to gate array of timer in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, timer

I want get a timer `foreach dataValue in _dataValues` which are stored in  array for example, `timer[0]=timer0`, `timer[1]=timer1`, `timer[2]=timer2` etc. Here is my code:

```
Timer[] timer = new Timer[50];

int i = 0;

foreach (int dataValue in _dataValues)
{             
     string a = "timer" + i;              
     timer[i] = a;
     i++;
     timer1[i].Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
     timer1[i].Interval = (1000) * (2);
 }
```

But it provide error *"Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Timer'"*. So how to get value in `timer[i]`? Any one can help me?

Comment: What is stored in `_dataValues` and where do you want to get `timer1` value from?

Comment: I think you now understand @pioter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not really clear what you are after. Here is a wild guess:

```
Timer[] timers = new Timer[50];
string timerNames = new string[50];

int i = 0;

foreach (int dataValue in _dataValues)
{    
     timeNames[i] = string.Format("{0}",i);
     timer[i] = new Timer();
     timer[i].Interval = dataValue;
     i++;
}
```

It is probably a bad idea to create 50 timers. If you want to have different intervals this can be done with a single timer too. Just create one timer with the shortest common interval.

Comment: This may be compliated - factoring et all. A timer is a quite leightweight object, they all use a queue internally. Like ONE queue for the next event.

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` is not really what I would consider lightweight. Each timer has its own GCHandle, ,involves P/Invoke for all operations and creates an object that has a finalizer. I also don't see `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` using a common queue you mentioned.

Comment: Hm, maybe not use THIS ONE then but the one in threading? Nothing in the code example indicates windows.forms. Plus all waht you name is still leightweiht, sorry. It p/invokes because it uses an internal timer mechanism in the windows os, NATURALLY it p/invokes-  the alternative would be starting it's own thread.

Comment: I think, only the `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` has the `Tick` event mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the bellow syntax

```
 public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            List<Timerx> timers = new List<Timerx>();
            foreach (int dataValue in Enumerable.Range(0, 10))
            {
                timers.Add(new Timerx() { TimerName = "Timer"+dataValue });
            }
        }
    }
    public class Timerx : Timer
    {
        public string TimerName { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to assign to a array of `Timer` just `string`. Try:

```
Timer[] timers=new Timer[50];

for (int index = 0; index < _dataValues.Length; index++)
{
     timers[index] = new Timer() { Interval = _dataValues[index] };
}
```

Also, if it's not fixed length of your `_dataValues` use strongly typed `List<T>`:

```
List<Timer> timers = new List<Timer>();
foreach (int dataValue in _dataValues)
{           
    timers.Add(new Timer() { Interval = dataValue });  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were attempting to create an array of timers with each timer being named according to its index.

But each timer already has a unique name: timers[0], timers[1], timers[2], etc. that would correctly identify each timer as though it were a named object:

```
    timers[i].Interval = 1000;
    timers[i].Elapsed += timer_Elapsed_i;
    timers[i].Start();
```